# Detecting battery module AVR removal

Tags: power, batteries, detection

I am working on a module (based on ATTiny) that will be plugged and unplugged onto a MCU systems. This MCU system powers up the ATtiny module and when this module is removed, the MCU system has to notified.
I though of tying the power from the module to the MCU so that a removal provoked a falling edge but I am not sure that would work.
Another option would be using a switch but I think I'll face problems when the gate is floating (the device remains closed)
A relay/optocoupler drains too much current and the only reliable solution I come up with is using an RC network.
Which one of these do you think it could work best?
Thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The circuit that you have shown will probably work for your purpose with some slight modifications.
1) Place a pull-down resistor on the gate of Q1, this way the gate will not be left floating it will have a well defined state when the module is unplugged.
2)I would place R1 on the drain of Q1, under the current configuration depending on the actual value of R1, Vcc and Vgs(threshold) of your device Q1 might end up in linear mode operation.